# Continue prompting user input until 0 is key in

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

i'm having problem with my code. Not sure how to fix it. My program repeatedly prompts for the supermarket aisle numbers to visit. When 0 is entered, the input process will terminate. Then the program computes the minimum distance based on the best location to place the shopping basket and the number of aisles I need to pick items from. The program then displays the minimum distance. The following are my code:

```
totalAisles = int(input("Enter the number of aisles in supermarket: "))
visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
if visitAisle == 0:
    print("Not visiting any aisle")
else:
    aisle = []
    while True:
        visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
        if visitAisle == 0:
            break
        else:
            for i in range(totalAisles):
                visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
                aisle.append(visitAisle)
                #to find the best aisle to place the basket 
                highestAisle = max(aisle)
                lowestAisle = min(aisle)
                basket = round(highestAisle + lowestAisle) / 2
                minimumDistance += abs(basket - visitAisle) * 2
            print(f"The minimum distance is {minimumDistance} units")
```

Example runs

Run 1
Enter number of aisles in supermarket: 100

Enter the aisle number to visit: 1

Enter the aisle number to visit: 8

Enter the aisle number to visit: 5

Enter the aisle number to visit: 4

Enter the aisle number to visit: 10

Enter the aisle number to visit: 0

The minimum distance is 26 units

Run 2

Enter number of aisles in supermarket: 100

Enter the aisle number to visit: 1

Enter the aisle number to visit: 0

The minimum distance is 0 units

Run 3

Enter number of aisles in supermarket: 100

Enter the aisle number to visit: 0

Not visiting any aisle

Comment: So you want it to end if visitAisle == 0 ? Do a while loop that ends once that condition is met.

Comment: I just checked it. For starters you didn't define minimumDistance before making calculations. And your for loop keeps asking for aisle to visit based on first input (totalAisles). It doesn't stop until it reaches that number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Here is a more streamlined way of doing it.  I also made sure the user doesn't enter duplicate aisle numbers and not more aisles than there are in the store.  Most importantly, the computation step is much simplified.

```
totalAisles = int(input("Enter the number of aisles in supermarket: "))
aisle = []
visitAisle = None

while len(aisle) < totalAisles:
    visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
    if visitAisle == 0:
        if aisle:
            break
        else:
            print("Not visiting any aisle")
            break
    if visitAisle not in aisle and visitAisle != 0:
        aisle.append(visitAisle)
    else:
        print("You already entered that aisle number. Pick another one.")

#to find the best aisle to place the basket
if aisle:
    highestAisle = max(aisle)
    lowestAisle = min(aisle)
    basket = (highestAisle + lowestAisle) //2

    #traveling back and forth from the basket to each isle
    minimumDistance = 0
    for visitAisle in aisle:
        minimumDistance += abs(basket - visitAisle) * 2
    print(f"\nThe minimum distance is {minimumDistance} units if you park the cart at aisle {basket}")
```

Comment: Thanks. However something is off with the formula. I didnt get the same results as the sample answer.

Comment: What is your sample answer. It would help to know what the expected output is for a given set of user responses.

Comment: That's an easy fix.  You can't include 0 in your average.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Though i seek your kind help in explaining the if aisle. What does the if aisle means? It occurs twice in the code, if aisle: break and also one finding the best aisle for the basket? Does if aisle: , means there are values inside the aisle[ ]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround which I suggest you

```
visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
if visitAisle == 0:
    print("Not visiting any aisle")
else:
    aisle = []
    while True:
        visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
        if visitAisle == 0:
            break
        else:
            for i in range(totalAisles):
                visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
                if visitAisle == 0:
                    break
                aisle.append(visitAisle)
                #to find the best aisle to place the basket 
                highestAisle = max(aisle)
                lowestAisle = min(aisle)
                basket = round(highestAisle + lowestAisle) / 2
                minimumDistance += abs(basket - visitAisle) * 2
        if visitAisle == 0:
                    break
    print("The minimum distance is ", minimumDistance)
```

I have modified few lines of the program, but only just a bit. Now I hope you can understand what was the reason for the issue.

Comment: This doesn't help. You forgot the first line totalAisles. Also, minimumDistance is still not defined before calculation.

Comment: Thanks. However something is off with the formula. I didnt get the same results as the sample answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure the output is exactly what you are looking for, this is an alternative.

```
totalAisles = int(input("Enter the number of aisles in supermarket: "))
enterStore = (input("Do you want to enter the store (yes/no)?: "))
if enterStore == "no":
    print("Not visiting the supermarket today!")
minimumDistance = 0
aisle = []
while enterStore != "no":
    visitAisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: "))
    if visitAisle == 0:
        break
    else:
        aisle.append(visitAisle)
        highestAisle = max(aisle)
        lowestAisle = min(aisle)
        basket = int(round(highestAisle + lowestAisle) / 2)
        minimumDistance += abs(basket - visitAisle) * 2

print(f"The minimum distance is {minimumDistance} units, ideal place for basket is {basket}")
```

Comment: Thanks. However something is off with the formula. I didnt get the same results as the sample answer.